# How to subtract the specified percentage between observations to perform complex arithmetic operations in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 datasets

```
    d1=structure(list(mdm = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), perc = c(50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 110L, 
115L, 120L, 130L, 140L, 150L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 110L, 
115L, 120L, 130L, 140L, 150L), price = c(38.9, 46.68, 54.46, 
62.24, 66.13, 70.02, 73.91, 74.688, 75.466, 76.244, 77.022, 77.8, 
78.578, 79.356, 80.134, 80.912, 81.69, 85.58, 89.47, 93.36, 101.14, 
108.92, 116.7, 38.9, 46.68, 54.46, 62.24, 66.13, 70.02, 73.91, 
74.688, 75.466, 76.244, 77.022, 77.8, 78.578, 79.356, 80.134, 
80.912, 81.69, 85.58, 89.47, 93.36, 101.14, 108.92, 116.7), count = c(175, 
160, 145, 130, 122.5, 115, 107.5, 106, 104.5, 103, 101.5, 100, 
98.5, 97, 95.5, 94, 92.5, 85, 77.5, 70, 55, 40, 25, 175, 160, 
145, 130, 122.5, 115, 107.5, 106, 104.5, 103, 101.5, 100, 98.5, 
97, 95.5, 94, 92.5, 85, 77.5, 70, 55, 40, 25), profit = c(2607.5, 
3628.8, 4416.7, 4971.2, 5160.925, 5292.3, 5365.325, 5372.928, 
5378.197, 5381.132, 5381.733, 5380, 5375.933, 5369.532, 5360.797, 
5349.728, 5336.325, 5234.3, 5073.925, 4855.2, 4242.7, 3396.8, 
2317.5, 2432.5, 3468.8, 4271.7, 4841.2, 5038.425, 5177.3, 5257.825, 
5266.928, 5273.697, 5278.132, 5280.233, 5280, 5277.433, 5272.532, 
5265.297, 5255.728, 5243.825, 5149.3, 4996.425, 4785.2, 4187.7, 
3356.8, 2292.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -46L
))
```

and second dataset represents the percentage values by which it is necessary to reduce or increase the value of `price` and `count` in `d1` also d2 contains the `cost`  column

```
    d2=structure(list(mdm = 7:8, elast = c(1.5, 1.5), cost = 24:25), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I'm having some troubles with complex arithmetic and I need help.
I'll try to describe my question in more detail.

I need for each `mdm` group to subtract the percentage indicated in `perc` column from the price value, where the `perc` column = 100. (100 is always the start value.)
For example for mdm=7, `perc=100` where `price=77.8`.
The next perc value is 99, i.e. less by 1, so subtract 1 percent from 77.8 and get 77.022. perc = 85, this means that from the starting point `77.8` we subtract 15% = 66.13, perc = 50, which means we subtract 50 percent from the starting point.
In a similar way, I need to add percentages up, for example 101, this means that 1 percent up from the price = 77.8 i.e. 78,578, thus forming the price column and so on.

Further, the price value with `perc = 100` has a value in the `count` column, in this example it is also = 100 (but this is not always the case).

I need to take the value from the `elast` column for each mdm group from `d2` dataset and this value is multiplied by the next percentage of 100. For example, where perc = 99 for mdm = 7, the value of 1.5 must be multiplied by 1 (100*1,5=101.5), where the value of `perc = 70`, then 30 * 1.5 (100-70=30) 30*1,5=45 100+45=145 and so on.

The last step for each mdm in data `d2` there is the cost price. This means that from the already formed `price column`, we must subtract the cost value, for example, for mdm = 7, `cost=24` from the price (38.9-24 = 14.9), this value is multiplied by the value in the `count` column, i.e. in this case 175. This action creates a new column profit=14.9*175=2607

In this reproducible example, the price column is all filled in by me for a sample. In raw data this table looks like this (indeed desired output in `d1 dataset`)
The initial data looks like this

```
   mdm perc price count
1    7   50    NA    NA
2    7   60    NA    NA
3    7   70    NA    NA
4    7   80    NA    NA
5    7   85    NA    NA
6    7   90    NA    NA
7    7   95    NA    NA
8    7   96    NA    NA
9    7   97    NA    NA
10   7   98    NA    NA
11   7   99    NA    NA
**12   7  100  77.8   100**
13   7  101    NA    NA
14   7  102    NA    NA
15   7  103    NA    NA
16   7  104    NA    NA
17   7  105    NA    NA
18   7  110    NA    NA
19   7  115    NA    NA
20   7  120    NA    NA
21   7  130    NA    NA
22   7  140    NA    NA
23   7  150    NA    NA
24   8   50    NA    NA
25   8   60    NA    NA
26   8   70    NA    NA
27   8   80    NA    NA
28   8   85    NA    NA
29   8   90    NA    NA
30   8   95    NA    NA
31   8   96    NA    NA
32   8   97    NA    NA
33   8   98    NA    NA
34   8   99    NA    NA
**35   8  100  77.8   100**
36   8  101    NA    NA
37   8  102    NA    NA
38   8  103    NA    NA
39   8  104    NA    NA
40   8  105    NA    NA
41   8  110    NA    NA
42   8  115    NA    NA
43   8  120    NA    NA
44   8  130    NA    NA
45   8  140    NA    NA
46   8  150    NA    NA
```

Thanks  for your any valuable help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)[d2, c("price", "count", "cost") :=
  .((price[perc == 100]/100)*perc, count[perc == 100] +
   (elast* count[perc == 100]-perc), i.cost), on = .(mdm)]
d1[, last_step := (price - cost) * count]
```

-output

```
> head(d1)
   mdm perc price count   profit cost last_step
1:   7   50 38.90   200 2607.500   24   2980.00
2:   7   60 46.68   190 3628.800   24   4309.20
3:   7   70 54.46   180 4416.700   24   5482.80
4:   7   80 62.24   170 4971.200   24   6500.80
5:   7   85 66.13   165 5160.925   24   6951.45
6:   7   90 70.02   160 5292.300   24   7363.20
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:
First we join both dataframes,
then we define the rules as you describe in detail (therefore it is easy to translate to code :-).
I think most challenging and tricky thinking is to fix the price value at 100% -> in this case `price[perc=100]`. The rest is described by your fantastic explanation:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(d2, by="mdm") %>% 
  group_by(mdm) %>% 
  mutate(price = (price[perc==100]/100)*perc,
         count = (count[perc==100]+(elast* count[perc==100]-perc)),
         last_step = (price-cost)*count)
```

```
 mdm  perc price count elast  cost last_step
   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
 1     7    50  38.9  175    1.5    24     2607.
 2     7    60  46.7  160    1.5    24     3629.
 3     7    70  54.5  145    1.5    24     4417.
 4     7    80  62.2  130    1.5    24     4971.
 5     7    85  66.1  122.   1.5    24     5161.
 6     7    90  70.0  115    1.5    24     5292.
 7     7    95  73.9  108.   1.5    24     5365.
 8     7    96  74.7  106    1.5    24     5373.
 9     7    97  75.5  104.   1.5    24     5378.
10     7    98  76.2  103    1.5    24     5381.
# … with 36 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to produce d1 from the original frame as follows:

```
d1 %>% 
  group_by(mdm) %>% 
  mutate(price = price[perc==100]*(1-(100-perc)/100)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  inner_join(d2, by="mdm") %>% 
  mutate(count = count[perc==100] + (100-perc)*elast, profit = count*(price-cost)) %>% 
  select(-c(elast,cost))
```

Input:

```
d1 = structure(list(mdm = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), perc = c(50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 110L, 
115L, 120L, 130L, 140L, 150L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 110L, 
115L, 120L, 130L, 140L, 150L), price = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 77.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 77.8, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), count = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))
```

Output:

```
   mdm perc   price count   profit
1    7   50  38.900 175.0 2607.500
2    7   60  46.680 160.0 3628.800
3    7   70  54.460 145.0 4416.700
4    7   80  62.240 130.0 4971.200
5    7   85  66.130 122.5 5160.925
6    7   90  70.020 115.0 5292.300
7    7   95  73.910 107.5 5365.325
8    7   96  74.688 106.0 5372.928
9    7   97  75.466 104.5 5378.197
10   7   98  76.244 103.0 5381.132
11   7   99  77.022 101.5 5381.733
12   7  100  77.800 100.0 5380.000
13   7  101  78.578  98.5 5375.933
14   7  102  79.356  97.0 5369.532
15   7  103  80.134  95.5 5360.797
16   7  104  80.912  94.0 5349.728
17   7  105  81.690  92.5 5336.325
18   7  110  85.580  85.0 5234.300
19   7  115  89.470  77.5 5073.925
20   7  120  93.360  70.0 4855.200
21   7  130 101.140  55.0 4242.700
22   7  140 108.920  40.0 3396.800
23   7  150 116.700  25.0 2317.500
24   8   50  38.900 175.0 2432.500
25   8   60  46.680 160.0 3468.800
26   8   70  54.460 145.0 4271.700
27   8   80  62.240 130.0 4841.200
28   8   85  66.130 122.5 5038.425
29   8   90  70.020 115.0 5177.300
30   8   95  73.910 107.5 5257.825
31   8   96  74.688 106.0 5266.928
32   8   97  75.466 104.5 5273.697
33   8   98  76.244 103.0 5278.132
34   8   99  77.022 101.5 5280.233
35   8  100  77.800 100.0 5280.000
36   8  101  78.578  98.5 5277.433
37   8  102  79.356  97.0 5272.532
38   8  103  80.134  95.5 5265.297
39   8  104  80.912  94.0 5255.728
40   8  105  81.690  92.5 5243.825
41   8  110  85.580  85.0 5149.300
42   8  115  89.470  77.5 4996.425
43   8  120  93.360  70.0 4785.200
44   8  130 101.140  55.0 4187.700
45   8  140 108.920  40.0 3356.800
46   8  150 116.700  25.0 2292.500
```